# How to get a particular field from JSON in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, jq

I need to implement a simple shell utility in Ruby which parses JSON from a file and return a particular field from it.

JSON examples to be parsed:

```
{"status": "fail", "messages": ["Out of capacity"]}

{"status": "success", "messages": [], "result": {"node": {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "description": "", "id": 974, "name": "VM#3"}}}
```

Idea is to create a CLI utility with two parameters: JSON file to read and field from JSON to extract:

```
./get_json_field.rb ~/tmp.XXXXXX 'result.node.ip'
./get_json_field.rb ~/tmp.XXXXXX 'messages.0'
```

I'm struggling how to map 2nd parameter to parsed JSON data structure in Ruby. I can write an iterator for sure, splitting string to an array using dot as separator an go through it item by item but this doesn't look like elegant solution.

Any suggestions for more elegant way?

Comment: Why doesn't that seem elegent?  It seems pretty natural to me!

Comment: I still thinking about map-like solution for that

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with splitting string and going through parts of it:

```
require 'json'

data1 = JSON.load('{"status": "fail", "messages": ["Out of capacity"]}')
data2 = JSON.load('{"status": "success", "messages": [], "result": {"node": {"ip": "1.2.3.4", "description": "", "id": 974, "name": "VM#3"}}}')

def get_from_json(data, query)
  query.split('.').inject(data) do |memo, key|
    key = key.to_i if memo.is_a? Array
    memo.fetch(key)
  end
end

get_from_json(data1, 'messages.0')        # => "Out of capacity"
get_from_json(data2, 'result.node.ip')    # => "1.2.3.4"
```

Comment: Yeah. I was about to write something like that. You just forgot to convert numbers. Because fetch '1' is not the same as fetch 1

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `jq` it might already do what you are looking for.

```
jq .messages[0]
jq .node.message.ip
```

See http://stedolan.github.com/jq/

Comment: While the question does specify "in ruby", it also mentions wanting "a simple shell utility" -- as such, I think this _may_ be the best answer here.  If, on the other hand, ruby really is a hard requirement for whatever reason, then let me also point out that there's a [ruby-jq](https://github.com/winebarrel/ruby-jq) library, which might also help fit the bill.